# File htaccees for a 404 page how to set?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi have this file htaccess, i need to improve a 404 page, now when you visit a page that not exist return the index.php content and the url doesn't change, i would like to put a custom 404 , i tried with "ErrorDocument 404" but doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ricercadilavoro.it  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ricercadilavoro.it/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this Wordpress .htaccess by any chance?

Comment: Your `ErrorDocument 404` will **NEVER** work, because it will redirect all non-existing stuff to `index.php`. That is, your `index.php` is a 404 handler itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ErrorDocument directive is the correct way to do this. Make sure you're using a path relative to the server root.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

For more information, read this http://www.apache.com/docs/httpd-docs-2.2.13.fr/mod/core.html#errordocument.

Comment: OP wrote `i tried with "ErrorDocument 404" but doesn't work.`

Comment: @anubhava What's probably happening is that the filepath he used is incorrect. There's no other way of specifying a custom 404 error in Apache as far as I'm concerned.